# Can I set up system mail to use an external SMTP server?

Tags: linux, smtp, email

Is it possible to set up system mail on a linux box to be sent via a different smtp server - maybe even with authentication? If so, how do I do this?

If that's unclear, let give an example. If I'm at the command line and type:

```
cat body.txt | mail -s "just a test" myfriend@hisdomain.com
```

is it possible to have that be sent via an external SMTP server, like G-mail ?

I'm not looking for "a way to send mail from gmail from the command line" but rather an option to configure the entire system to use a specific SMTP server, or possibly one account on an SMTP server (maybe overriding the from address).

Comment: It's the way most machines used to be set up, in fact. Do you have any particular MTA in mind? If not (this includes “what is an MTA?”), what distribution are you running?

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 10.04, found [this article](http://www.howtogeek.com/51819/how-to-setup-email-alerts-on-linux-using-gmail/) on setting up ssmtp, seems like it might work. can you elaborate more on how most machines are set up?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

I found sSMTP very simple to use.

In Debian based systems:

```
apt-get install ssmtp
```

Then edit the configuration file in /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf

A sample configuration to use your gmail for sending e-mails:

```
# root is the person who gets all mail for userids < 1000
root=your@email.com

# Here is the gmail configuration (or change it to your private smtp server)
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587
AuthUser=your@gmail.com
AuthPass=yourGmailPass
UseTLS=YES
UseSTARTTLS=YES
```

**Note**: Make sure the "mail" command is present in your system. mailutils package should provide this one in Debian based systems.

**Update**: There are people (and bug reports for different Linux distributions) reporting that sSMTP will not accept passwords with a 'space' or '#' character. If sSMTP is not working for you, this may be the case.

Comment: as a note to others you may have to install ssmtp and then mailutils. i think mailutils sets up the mail command and symlinks to ssmtp so you can use the regular `mail` syntax :)

Comment: @cwd Just tested on Ubuntu 13.04. I didn't have to install `mailutils` package (and it's not installed automaticaly). `ssmtp` worked out-of-the box.

Comment: I just successfully used this in Debian on a BeagleBone Black and did have to install mailutils first.

Comment: On Kubuntu 14.04, had to install *mailutils* after ssmtp. However it worked at first try.

Comment: ssmtp does NOT verify the SSL/TLS certificate of the remote server on the current debian, ubuntu and redhat releases and also does NOT verify the hostname of the certificate. This is a major issue, as this effectively renders the encryption useless and your password is being transmitted alike to being plaintext and anyone can sniff it. ssmtp has had no active development since atleast 2009. So, if you care about the security of the email account you use for your servers outgoing emails, do NOT use ssmtp, but postfix (or something else) instead: unix.stackexchange.com/a/118101/72087

Comment: Can you please provide some more details about your claims that sSMTP is not under active development anymore, as well as the security issue? Some link where it is discussed further maybe?

Comment: I had to activate `FromLineOverride=YES` in order to send mails successfully

Comment: @VangelisTasoulas That is already linked to from the discussion. You could try to do the minimal work yourself next time. Following the links I found the Debian GIT repo for SSMTP. It has seen no active development for the last decade: https://anonscm.debian.org/gitweb/?p=ssmtp/ssmtp.git

Comment: @oligofren very kind of you to try to do the minimal work for me and failing to provide any value to this discussion. sSMTP is unmaintained with regards to adding new features, but that doesn't make a program useless as long as there are proper security updates in place. Debian and Red Hat take security very seriously and patch outstanding issues. Is there any outstanding security issue that hasn't been patched yet? If yes, please point me to it and do not be arrogant. And BTW, the latest version of SSMTP has been shipped in 2014. Someone probably forgot to push their changes in the git repo.

Comment: @VangelisTasoulas You are right, I was a bit condescending. Sorry for that.

Comment: There seems there is some activity here: https://salsa.debian.org/debian/ssmtp/commits/master. So while it may not be an active development, the package doesn't look abandoned either.

Answer (score 28):

For **postfix**:

- Add the IP for your external mail-relay to `/etc/hosts` and add an alias mailrelay to it.
- Modify the postfix configuration:

  ```
  relayhost = [mailrelay]
  smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
  smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/smtp_auth
  smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
  ```
- Edit `/etc/postfix/smtp_auth`

  ```
  mailrelay login:password
  ```
- Convert into **hash-format**

`postmap /etc/postfix/smtp_auth`

No need to say that only root should be able to read this... `chmod u=r,og=-`

Answer (score 20):

mailx supports setting the smtp server on the CLI...

```
echo "message" | mailx -S smtp=$smtphost:$smtpport -s "subject line" -v foo@baa.com
```

Nothing needs to be installed, provided your smtp server lets you send un-authenticated mail.

There is no one answer that sets the smtp server for **all** the bits of software you might have on your Linux box. Each email client can configure a SMTP server.

Comment: Be sure to put `-S var=val` _before_ your recipient.

Comment: What to do if un-authenticated mail is not allowed? I got
Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL,

Comment: https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-mailx/

Comment: My Debian version of mailx doesn't work as above, instead I have to used heirloom-mailx or s-nail

Comment: where can i find info on that -S option? i can't find that in any man page anywhere.

Answer (score 8):

My favorite is the [email](https://www.deanproxy.com/code) ([github](https://github.com/deanproxy/eMail)) client. It's really simple, no complex configuration needed, no dependencies needed. And you can specify smtp-server argument via command line, which means it's more suitable for scripting. The only pity is that most linux distributions does not contains this tool, so you need to compile it yourself.

Quotes from [email project on github](https://github.com/deanproxy/eMail)

> Q: What is 'email' ?
>
> A:  'email' is a program I designed that will send email via the
>   command line
>       to remote smtp servers or use 'sendmail' internally, and fully interact with
>       GNUPG to encrypt and sign your e-mails, so you decide to do so...
>       You can get GNUPG at: http://www.gnupg.org

Thank [cygwin](http://cygwin.com) for let me known this useful [email](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Femail%2Femail-3.2.3-git-2&grep=email) client.

## Compile and install

```
./configure
make
./install.sh --version 3.1.3 --prefix /usr --mandir /usr/share/man --sysconfdir /etc
```

## Command line options of email

```
$ email --help
Options information is as follows
email [options] recipient1,recipient2,...

    -h, -help module          Print this message or specify one of the below options
    -V, -verbose              Display mailing progress.
    -f, -from-addr            Senders mail address
    -n, -from-name            Senders name
    -b, -blank-mail           Allows you to send a blank email
    -e, -encrypt              Encrypt the e-mail for first recipient before sending
    -s, -subject subject      Subject of message
    -r, -smtp-server server   Specify a temporary SMTP server for sending
    -p, -smtp-port port       Specify the SMTP port to connect to
    -a, -attach file          Attach file and base64 encode
    -c, -conf-file file       Path to non-default configuration file
    -t, -check-config         Simply parse the email.conf file for errors
    -x, -timeout              Set socket timeout.
        -cc email,email,...   Copy recipients
        -bcc email,email,...  Blind Copy recipients
        -sign                 Sign the email with GPG
        -html                 Send message in HTML format ( Make your own HTML! )
        -tls                  Use TLS/SSL
    -m, -smtp-auth type       Set the SMTP AUTH type (plain or login)
    -u, -smtp-user username   Specify your username for SMTP AUTH
    -i, -smtp-pass password   Specify your password for SMTP AUTH
    -g, -gpg-pass             Specify your password for GPG
    -H, -header string        Add header (can be used multiple times)
        -high-priority        Send the email with high priority
        -no-encoding          Don't use UTF-8 encoding
```

## Sample usage

### Simple mail with SMTP server specified

```
echo "mail body" | email -subject "unix.stackexchange.com Q36982" -from-name LiuYan刘研 -from-addr liuyan@domain.com -smtp-server smtp.domain.com -smtp-port 25 cwd@your-domain.com your-friends@his-domain.com
```

### HTML mail

```
echo "<h1>header</h1><p>paragraph</p>" | email -html -subject "unix.stackexchange.com Q36982 HTML mail" cwd@your-domain.com
```

### Attachment(s)

```
echo "see the attachment(s)" | email -subject "This is my email.conf file" -attach /etc/email/email.conf -attach cwd@your-domain.com
```

Comment: Hello, the first link ("cleancode.rg") is dead (and spam).

Comment: @Ehvince Thanks, links are updated now.

Answer (score 2):

Set up a local exim SMTP server by following the instructions on [this](http://library.linode.com/email/exim/send-only-mta-ubuntu-10.04-lucid) page, but choose the "mail sent by smarthost; no local mail" option from the [first](http://library.linode.com/email/exim/send-only-mta-ubuntu-10.04-lucid#sph_configure-exim-for-local-mail-service) screen of the Exim configuration. This will set up an SMTP server on your box that can receive mail from the "mail" or "mailx" commands and will forward all messages to the smarthost (a Gmail server in your case) for delivery.

To send outgoing email through a Gmail server you will need to set up [TLS support for Exim](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch39.html), which is not trivial. This [Howto](http://www.howtoforge.com/exim-authenticated-smarthost) gives some explanation and [here's](http://thepaulprog.blogspot.com/2009/02/making-exim4-send-outgoing-mail-through.html) a link with further explanation specific to Gmail. You should allow yourself several hours to get this working. I would suggest starting by sending email from your box to a TLS enabled SMTP server to which you have root access so that you can debug your Exim TLS configuration from both sides before trying to send though a Gmail server. Since the communication is encrypted, you wont be able to use tools like tcpdump to analyze the protocol on the line.

Answer (score 1):

If you have external smtp server connectivity with your host then you can configure smtp on your host and send emails.

Smtp configuration in linux steps can be found here : http://kerneltalks.com/config/guide-smtp-configuration-linux/

Email comand examples can be found here : http://kerneltalks.com/commands/examples-send-email-through-terminal/

Comment: Answers should include enough detail to stand on their own.  Having links with more comprehensive information is fine, but at least a portion of the linked material should be quoted in the answer so it can be useful after link rot sets in.