# Does the mail command require a mail server?

Tags: mail-command

Does one need to set up a mail server before being able to use the linux `mail` command?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I set up system mail to use an external SMTP server?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36982/can-i-set-up-system-mail-to-use-an-external-smtp-server)

Comment: @slm not really the same as that question hints that one needs an SMTP server to run mail, but I'm asking whether it is absolutely necessary

Comment: Yeah it's a possible duplicate, I've answered you b/c that Q takes it a bit too specific. Still feels like a dup but I answered you anyway 8-)

Answer (score 17):

No you do not require a mail server to send mail. I'm most familiar with Sendmail and there are 3 classifications of functionality that fulfill email as a service. MDA (Mail Delivery Agents) is 1, and MTA (Mail Transfer Agents) is 2, and 3 is MUA (Mail User Agents).

The terminology get's confusing but you do not require an MTA to be running all the time. The MTA will be called each time the MUA (`mail`) wants to "send" mail.

When you run `mail` and you specify an address to send mail to, `sam@example.com`. The mail client will summon the MTA (`/usr/bin/sendmail`) which will then query DNS for that host/domain (example.com), and find out what value is designated for its MX record. MX stands for Mail Exchanger.

#### Example

You can use the `dig` command to see this:

```
$ dig gnu.org mx

; <<>> DiG 9.7.4-P1-RedHat-9.7.4-2.P1.fc14 <<>> gnu.org mx
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 21053
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 2

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;gnu.org.           IN  MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
gnu.org.        299 IN  MX  10 eggs.gnu.org.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
eggs.gnu.org.       299 IN  A   208.118.235.92
eggs.gnu.org.       299 IN  AAAA    2001:4830:134:3::10

;; Query time: 218 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.8#53(192.168.1.8)
;; WHEN: Thu Oct  3 17:27:22 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 90
```

So the client will attempt to connect to eggs.gnu.org on port 25 to deliver this email.

#### DNS server?

@puk asked the following follow-up question:

> Is this DNS on my local machine?

To which I replied:

@puk - it can be in the same manner that the mail server can be, but typically it's not. Look in your `/etc/resolv.conf` file and also when you run the `dig` command you'll notice the `SERVER: ...` line at the bottom. That's the DNS server servicing your request.

#### Example

My `/etc/resolv.conf` file contains the following:

```
nameserver 192.168.1.8
```

And queries such as this one, using `dig`:

```
$ dig gnu.org mx
```

Result in this at the bottom:

```
;; Query time: 259 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.8#53(192.168.1.8)
;; WHEN: Thu Oct  3 17:46:13 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 90
```

And for the astute reader, one my ask, how is this configured? The answer is the `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file. Specifically this line:

```
hosts:      files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
```

That says, use files first (`/etc/hosts`), followed by `mdns4_minimal`. That's a multicast DNS. It's basically a cache of previous look ups. Lastly it uses `dns` which is the IP address of the `nameserver` designated in the `/etc/resolv.conf` file.

Comment: Is this DNS on my local machine?

Comment: @puk - see updates.

Comment: @puk - I've added more....

Answer (score 9):

It really depends on which version of `mail` you are using.

All versions need an MTA to actually deliver the mail, but some versions are capable of using SMTP to talk to a remote MTA (the "smarthost", e.g. your ISP's mail server) and some can only pipe the message to `/usr/sbin/sendmail` to send the mail via a local MTA.

In the latter case, the local MTA could be a full-fledged MTA like [sendmail](http://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/) or [exim](http://www.exim.org/) or [postfix](http://www.postfix.org/).  Or it could be a simple send-only MTA like [nullmailer](http://untroubled.org/nullmailer/) or [ssmtp](https://wiki.debian.org/sSMTP). Or a slightly more sophisticated mini-MTA like [msmtp](http://msmtp.sourceforge.net/) that also supports queuing mail for later delivery.

In the Free Software & Open Source world, there are two main variants of the `mailx` package (which provides the `mail` command): `bsd-mailx`, and `heirloom-mailx`.  The `mail` command is also available in GNU `mailutils`.

[bsd-mailx](http://packages.debian.org/sid/bsd-mailx) does not speak SMTP and can only send mail by piping it to `/usr/sbin/sendmail`

[heirloom-mailx](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/mailx.html) can speak SMTP to a smarthost as well as the traditional 'pipe-to-sendmail' method.  BTW, [S-nail](https://www.sdaoden.eu/code.html) is probably the best derivative of heirloom-mailx - it is still being actively developed and updated.

[GNU mailutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/mailutils/) contains several mail-related tools for both end-users and systems administrators, including a version of `mail` and much more.

So, to answer your question "Do you need a mail server?".  Yes, sort of.  You need one but, depending on which version of `mail` you have installed, you may not have to install and configure it on your own system.

IMO, you are better off with at least a minimal MTA like `msmtp` (or a full-fledged one like `postfix` or `exim`) than relying solely on a smarthost with `heirloom-mailx` because you still need to queue mail for later delivery when your internet connection is down or your smarthost is unreachable.  With a local queue, `mail` and `crond` and other programs can just send-and-forget any mail.  Without a local queue, they have to deal somehow with the error condition if the smarthost is unavailable.

Comment: When you type "mail" on a fresh Ubuntu install, it says `Command 'mail' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install mailutils` -- is it better to use bsd-mailx or heirloom-mailx instead of mailutils?

Comment: No, unless you intend to use it as a command-line mail client then just use GNU mailutils or [s-nail](https://www.sdaoden.eu/code.html) which is based on heirloom-mailx (and if want a text-mode mail client, use `mutt` instead).   If you already have an MTA like postfix or exim installed, use its version of `/usr/sbin/sendmail` for just sending messages - that will give more control over both envelope and header From, and other headers too.  If you want to send properly formed complex mime messages from the command-line, use something like [mime-construct](http://www.argon.org/~roderick/)

Comment: All of these should be packaged for Ubuntu - they are for Debian.