# Executing command for sendmail not working

Tags: rhel, email, sendmail, mailx

Good Day, I'm still new in Linux CLI and I'm using RHEL 6. I'm executing command for sending email via terminal.

```
$ cat log.txt | mail -s "Logs" myemail@e.mail.com
```

Hosted by outlook365

When I try this command, nothing happens. No errors but nothing happens.

Any tips?

Thank you.

Comment: command is correct, you should check logs for errors

Comment: @LevBystritskiy Do I need to setup any smtp ?

Comment: Usually no, but may be you mail is blocked by external server (that's why logs needed), also you can setup external server for this -  check http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36982/can-i-set-up-system-mail-to-use-an-external-smtp-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the /var/log/maillog to see the logs related to the email being sent.   Are the logs logging any errors?