# How can I make GNU mailutils to use an external SMTP server?

Tags: email, smtp, mail-command, mail-transport-agent

Does anybody on this planet know what the equivalent GNU `mailutils` command to the following looks like?
Is this even possible without a local MTA with `mailutils`?
Using `s-nail` it works as intended.

```bsh
s-nail -s "$subject" -S $smtp_server -r $from_user $to <<<$message
```

according to the GNU [mailutils manual](https://mailutils.org/manual/mailutils.html#index-sendmail)
I tried:

```bsh
mail --subject "$subject" \
 --set smtp=$smtp_server \
 --exec "set sendmail=smtp://$smtp_server" \
 --append "From:$from_user" \
 $to <<<$message
```

> mail: Cannot open mailer: Input/output error 
> mail: cannot send message: Input/output error

this is not a duplicate of [can-i-set-up-system-mail-to-use-an-external-smtp-server](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36982/can-i-set-up-system-mail-to-use-an-external-smtp-server) as they used a local MTA or heirloom-mailx or `s-nail` or other tools. I am using Debian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it.

on default `mailutils` *mailer url* (smtp://$smtp_server) uses *startls*.
Found it using *verbose* mode:

```bsh
mail --subject "$subject" \
 --exec "set sendmail=smtp://$smtp_server" \
 --exec 'set verbose' \
 --append "From:$from_user" \
 $to <<<$message
```

> mail: S: 220 xxx ESMTP 
> mail: C: EHLO xxx 
> mail: S: 250-xxx 
> mail: S: 250-PIPELINING 
> mail: S: 250-SIZE 10240000 
> mail: S: 250-ETRN 
> mail: S: 250-STARTTLS 
> mail: S: 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN 
> mail: S: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 
> mail: S: 250-8BITMIME 
> mail: S: 250-DSN 
> mail: S: 250 CHUNKING 
> mail: C: STARTTLS 
> mail: S: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS 
> mail: C: EHLO xxx 
> mail: Cannot open mailer: Input/output error 
> mail: cannot send message: Input/output error

giving *mailer url* the [notls](https://mailutils.org/manual/mailutils.html#SMTP-Mailboxes) parameter solves it:

```bsh
mail --subject "$subject" \
 --exec "set sendmail=smtp://$smtp_server;notls" \
 --exec 'set verbose' \
 --append "From:$from_user" \
 $to <<<$message
```

Comment: I strongly recommand you or anyone who see this post, do not use `smtp://` url with your username/password in url, or your password will be sent in plain text without tls encryption. Use the `smtps://` url to secure your password.